# How do I only build the last commit in Azure Pipelines for CI/CD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

The [azure pipeline build task](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines) for github tends to build all the commits in a PR sent. I would like it to build only the last commit. That is I would like the other build jobs started for the previous commits in a PR (except for the last one) to be cancelled automatically without manual intervention. This is to reduce the number of build jobs queued at the same time for a given PR.

How do I achieve this in Azure Pipelines for CI/CD. I can do it in [travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#building-only-the-latest-commit) easily and would like to find out if it is available in Azure Pipelines for CI/CD and if so how to achieve it.?

Comment: can you please add more explanation to it, I'm not very familiar with Travis and want to understand the problem. snapshots are appreciated.

Comment: This is how travis works: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#building-only-the-latest-commit . In a branch or PR it will build only the last commit and the other commits that are queued would be cancelled.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the exact requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure where you see this happening. I use Pipelines for a couple of GitHub projects and creating a PR only creates one build that builds the complete PR. Do you have a sample project where this happens or can you share some screenshots?

Comment: I mean after creating a PR if you push another commit to the same branch or force push, it will queue a new build for each commit. I would like to cancel the previous builds and retain only the last build for a PR so that the number of jobs is small.

Comment: I haven use AD Pipelines with GitHub, but not with a PR, but with my previous usage of AD Pipelines and PRs in the past, it should not build each commit in a PR.  Maybe you have batched builds enabled/disabled?  Maybe squash merges?

Comment: How do I check if batch builds are enabled or disabled? Yes I squash commits and force push to have only one commit per PR

Answer (score 1):

I believe this behavior to cancel existing queued pipelines on PR update became the default behavior for Azure-DevOps with the Nov-12-2018 release with this [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-143-update#setting-to-auto-cancel-an-existing-pipeline-when-a-pull-requests-is-updated).  It doesn't look like it is flagged for 2019 On-Premise, so I'd expect this won't be available On-Premise for a while.